# How to put columns names to a matrix from values from a vector?

Tags: r, matrix

I am trying to name the columns of matrix from data from a vector.

suppose I have the following matrix:

```
A <- matrix(1:110, ncol=11)
```

and also a vector with  11  values from read.table:

```
code <- data1$code
```

I would like to do something like:

```
colnames(A)=data.frame(code)
```

to put the names of the columns using the values from the vector code

Comment: What error do you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be far simpler just to pass `code` (or perhaps `as.character(code)`, if it is a factor variable

```
colnames(A) <- as.character(code)
```

Passing a `data.frame` with one column will not work, as this has `length =1` (the one column).

A `data.frame` is a  `list` with two elements of the correct lengths to `dimnames` you could set both `rownames` and `colnames` at the same time.